# estimating the total number of balls (n) after 2 draws of k balls

Tags: estimation, sampling

The problem is predicting the total number of balls (n) after 2 draws of k balls.
After the first draw of k balls, we have marked them so we can see if we had them before.
The balls are returns and we draw k balls again. some of them will be marked (m), meaning we have drawn them a second time.
What is n predicted by (k,m) and the confidence intervals. n~f(k,m) [CI]

Thank you.

Comment: This is called ["capture-recapture sampling"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=capture%20recapture) or ["mark and recapture sampling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture).

Comment: thank you @whuber, "Mark and recapture" is exactly what I was looking for!